# Can I change the appearance of my character?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm playing Dragon Age Inquisition on the XBox One, but after a few hours of playing the game I no longer like the way my character looks.

Is there a way for me to change the appearance of the main character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the "The Black Emporium" free DLC for this. Once you have downloaded and installed it, you can access it through your war map. The room has a "Mirror of transformation" which allows you to change your appearance.